# html download attribute filepath issue

Tags: html

I am trying to use the download attribute to get a document from my filesystem, but when I click I get failed - no file. As far as I can tell from other examples, the path looks ok but still nothing. Also, the full link when I check in inspector is mysite/filepath as if its a page on the site, is that how it normally is or am I doing something wrong here? The directory with the files is /var/www/files and the file name is correct.

Here is the relevant html

```
<table>
   <other rows here>
 <td> 
   <a href="/var/www/files/filename.extension">Download</a> 
 </td>
</table>
```

I get no error and my access log shows the following:

```
"GET /var/www/doctor_files/06-10-2016-17-30-DetectRTC%20(2).jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 582
```

Comment: `404` means you got an error.  A 404 error.

Comment: I know, I meant otherwise no error but not finding the file is my issue, so of course there is a 404

Comment: If your server isn't displaying any indication of the 404 error, it's very likely that it's a server configuration issue for that part of the problem.  Unfortunately, that's better answered over at http://serverfault.com/.  It would help to know what environment you're running and if you're using any frameworks.  Regardless, the answers below are probably right.  You probably just need to change the url to  `/files/filename.extension` or `/doctor_files/filename.extension`.  Perhaps even `/filename.extension` is correct.  All that depends on what your web root is.

Comment: the root is var/www/html, so i changed the path to /../files/file.ext, but still nothing!

Comment: Good thinking on the `..`, but unfortunately it's likely outside of the context of the web server file system scope.  You'll need to move your downloadable files into a subdirectory of `/var/www/html/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify relative path to your root web server. Wich is usually `/var/www/`, so omit this part. Try:

```
<a href="/files/filename.extension">Download</a>
```

Comment: How do you make it download in a new tab/window? I don't want to have the current page navigate to some other page.

Comment: To open a link in a new tab/window, just add attribute target="_blank".

Comment: It's not working. If there's an error (404, 5xx, or some other error) the current page navigates to the url with the error.

Answer (score 3):

> I get no error
>
> …
>
> 404

That is an error. It is a 404 Not Found error.

You are setting the value of the `href` attribute to a *file path* on your local filesystem.

You need to set it to a URL on your webserver.

The root of your webserver is probably `/var/www` so you need to omit that from the URL.